# How can I save my uploaded file into the SQL database?

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, upload

I made a page where you can upload a file, and it will be stored into the database, but it doesn't work, and I cant figure out why this is. Here is my code:

HTML

```
<form id="upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

PHP (on the same page)

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['file']['size'] > 0)
{
$file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];

$parser = fopen($file_tmp, 'r');
$content = fread($parser, filesize($file_tmp));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($parser);

if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $file_name = addcslashes($file_name);
}
include('config.php');
$conn->query("SET NAMES utf8");

$query="INSERT INTO files (name, size, type, content, status)"."VALUES (:name, :size, :type, :content, 'Iedereen') ";
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $file_name);
$stmt->bindParam(':size', $file_size);
$stmt->bindParam(':type', $file_type);
$stmt->bindParam(':content', $content);
$stmt->execute();
}
?>
```

Comment: Which error message did you get?

Comment: You are using prepared statements, so you should remove the calls to `addslashes()`. Also, what does the `content` field look like in the database?

Comment: content is a medium blob, and im not getting errors, just nothing happens

Comment: the page just refreshes (i use jquery mobile)

Comment: If you use javascript to post your form, you need to show that here as well.

Comment: im not using javascript for it, this is all

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['upload'])` - never true, because your form does not contain a control that is named `upload`.

Comment: that works, but now I get this error: Notice: Undefined index: file

Comment: You want to upload a file so need to write this in your code.

Comment: $query = ("update `table_name` SET `files_field`='{$destination}' WHERE file_name = $_COOKIE[id]") or die (mysql_error);

Comment: for form you need to write like this. <form action = "upload.php" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
 <input type = "hidden" name = "MAX_FILE_SIZE" value = "30000000"/><br><br>
 <input type = "file" name = "upload" value = "upload file"/><br><br>
 <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit"/>
</form>

Comment: but i dont want to update, i want to upload and save in my database

Comment: If you do not update the file it's not uploaded and save in database.

Answer (score -1):

this is the way i uploaded my images to the database called realestate easily ... just follow the code and change field names, table name and database name .

```
<form class="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" />
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">update</button> 
</form>
<?php   

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $filetmp = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    // rename image
    $div = explode('.', $filename);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($div));
    $unique_name = substr(md5(time()), 0,10).'.'.$file_ext;
    $path = "images/".$unique_name;
    move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$path);
    $query = "INSERT INTO files(name,path) VALUES 
    ('$filename','$path')";                            
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    if (mysqli_query($conn,$query)) {
        echo "Records updated successfully.";        
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $delete. " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
?>

$conn is my database connection variable.
```